# Blue Prism - Spy mode for JNLP application

Tags: java, jnlp, blueprism

Am working on BP with jnlp application. i have enabled the JAB also, but still the JAVA mode is not coming.

Please assist.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And most importantly create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve So please improve your question, otherwise nobody will and can help you. What did you try? Which versions of the software are u using? Whats the error? You have to provide much more than that...